# What happens exactly when formatting a drive within Windows and choosing the Restore Device Defaults button?

Tags: windows, filesystems, formatting

When choosing to format a drive from within Windows/File Explorer, one of the options presented is called "Restore Device Defaults" - however, it's not immediately obvious as to what the above option does or how it works. Is Windows able to somehow determine the default settings used on a drive and format the drive using these settings?

Comment: It quite literally resets the "File System", "Allocation unit size", "Capacity", and "Volume label" to their default values for the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Restore device defaults" changes the options in the "Format" window
back to the Windows defaults for whatever drive is selected,
as regarding the file-system format and the sector size.
This undoes changes done by the user and returns the relevant fields
to their initial values from when the dialog was initially invoked.

NTFS is the default for most internal hard drives while variations of FAT are
generally used for memory cards and USB sticks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not factory defaults, but program's defaults.

*File system* is reset to a sensible default for the selected device. *Allocation unit size* changes to *Default allocation size*, which translates to one of the remaining options depending on drive's capacity.